# all images are fading

Tags: html, css

I need four different pictures on this page to fade in and out. I have also added a logo and for some reason the logo fades along with the pictures, although I have no idea how. I would also like to make the nav bar fill the width of the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<style>

body {
    background-image: url("bg.jpg");
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;

    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:  #000000;
    margin-left:100px;
}
li {
    float:left;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
    background-color:  #000000;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
   margin-top:10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
            img:nth-of-type(1){
                 -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 20s linear 20s infinite;
            }
            img:nth-of-type(2){
                 -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 20s linear 15s infinite;
            }
            img:nth-of-type(3){
                 -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 20s linear 10s infinite;
            }
            img:nth-of-type(4){
                 -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 20s linear 0s infinite;
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes fadeInOut{

            0% { opacity:1; } 
            17% { opacity:1; } 
            25% { opacity:0; } 
            92% { opacity:0; } 
            100% { opacity:1; }

            }
.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px; // change to whatever works for you 
}
.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.container {
  width: 1000px;
}
.logo { 
  float: left; 
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
.nav { 
  float: right; 
  width: 880px;

}
</style>

<title>Badass Burgers</title>

</head>
<body>

<!--Top Navigation Links (top horizontal navigation bar)-->

  <img class="logo" src='logo.jpg'/>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav">

  <li><a class="active" href="info.php">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.php">Team</a></li>
  <li><a href="Menu.php">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
  <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
 <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img class="image" src='food1.jpg' width="1400" height="600" />
    <img class="image" src='Food2.jpg' width="1400" height="600" />
    <img class="image" src='Food3.jpg' width="1400" height="600" />
    <img class="image" src='Food4.jpg' width="1400" height="600" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Side note, `//` isn't valid for CSS comments. Need `/* */`

Comment: @j08691 unless it's sass,... which I don't think so ;)

Comment: I'm sometimes lazy and add an `x-` 'vendor prefix'. ;-)

Comment: @GolezTrol - whenever I want to comment out a CSS property for testing I pretty much to the same thing, but just with an x (50% less typing!)

Answer (score 1):

`img:nth-of-type(1){` is the first image. The first image is the logo. So either start numbering at 2, or (better), make the selector more specific, for instance:

```
.image-wrapper img:nth-of-type(1){
```

Same goes for the others as well, of course.